# Continuous Deployment для локального проекта

Tags: java, git, tomcat, развертывание, непрерывная-интеграция

Я разрабатываю учебное вэб-приложение на Java, использоваться оно будет локально.

Среда разработки:

- Windows
- Eclipse
- Git
- В качестве сервлет контейнера предполагаю использовать Apache Tomcat

Хочу автоматизировать деплой (локальный) - т.е. чтобы при коммите мое вэб-приложение автоматически собиралось и помещалось в Tomcat (установленный локально, соответственно). Подскажите, плиз, как это делается и с помощью какого ПО?

Comment: можно Jenkins использовать - https://www.jenkins.io/

Comment: ну или [Teamcity](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/teamcity/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала я опишу принципиальную схему, а конкретные инструменты опишу после.

Схема такая:

1. после комита нужно собрать приложение (создать *.war файл)
2. созданный файл развернуть на tomcat

### Сборка по комиту

Тут есть два варианта.

Либо использовать [post-commit хук](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git), чтоб сам гит извещал о комите.

Либо какой-то процесс должен периодически проверять изменения и запускать сборку.

### Развертывание (deploy) на томкат

У томката есть несколько возможностей развертывать приложения:

1. Есть просто [копирование war-файла](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server) в папку с веб-приложениями
2. Есть специальное приложение Tomcat Manager с [web API](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_a_Directory_or_WAR_by_URL) для развертывания
3. Есть [библиотека](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_using_the_Client_Deployer_Package), которая интегрируется с `ant` и позволяет среди прочего разворачивать приложение.

### Инструменты

Наверное, самый простой способ это написать самому скрипт который будет состоять из двух шагов:

1. собирать приложение в war-файл (`mvn package` если используется `maven` c [соответствующим](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) плагином)
2. копировать war-файл в папку з web приложениями tomcat

Далее нужно:

1. добавить `post-commit` хук, чтобы скрипт запускался при комите. [Тут](http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/automatically-triggering-jenkins-build.html) эта тема затронута для windows в более широком контексте.
2. настроить [автоматическое развертывание](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server), чтобы после шага 2 скрипта приложение подхватывалось томкатом

Нужно понимать, что continuous deployment это довольно непростая процедура, так как обычно она включает среди прочего:

1. запуск тестов во время сборки (и отчеты если что-то не так)
2. интеграционное тестирование (+отчеты)
3. сама процедура развертывания приложения может потребовать мигрировать данные в БД.
4. [smoke тестирование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_test) после развертывания
5. возможность отката на предыдущую версию, если что-то пошло не так.

В случае локального использования, не все из этого нужно, но кое-что может понадобиться (как например, миграции БД, если требуется делать развертывание системы не с нуля каждый раз, а с сохранением данных). Зависит от ваших требований конечно.

Более сложный в настройке вариант, но и дающий больше возможностей, это использование системы типа [jenkins](http://jenkins.io/). В этом случае есть готовые [плагины](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/), которые могут помочь решить некоторые из описанных задач.

Цена за это удобство сложность конфигурирования и необходимость администрирования. В этом случае может быть удобно запускать jenkins в docker для удобства развертывания самого jenkins.

Comment: Есть некоторая путаница в терминах, обычно `continuous deployment` означает только деплой. Если говорить о полном цикле, это будет уже `continuous delivery`. Сам часто путаюсь в этих понятиях.

Comment: "Только деплой" - это и есть деплой, нет смысла добавлять еще что-то. Обычно `continuous deployment` процес включает в себя `continuous delivery` и добавляет новый шаг - собственно развертывание на production системе. Посмотрите [тут](https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/principles/continuous-integration-vs-delivery-vs-deployment) или [тут](https://www.plutora.com/blog/continuous-integration-continuous-delivery-continuous-deployment).

Comment: Ха, походу вы правы. Как я сказал, сам часто путаюсь в этих словечках :)